# First time with Android, need help with adding media

Tags: music, storage, google-play-music, doubletwist

For Christmas this year I am getting a 16GB (really 10.6 GB) Galaxy Note II, which will be my first Android device after having a slew of iDevices. I have ~12 GB of music in iTunes and Google Music, and am looking for a way to sync it to my SD card (it doesn't fit in internal memory).

So far what I've looked at:

-dragging folders from my mac's Finder into the phone's raw file system

This would work, but when I get new songs it seems cumbersome to have to go back into the filesystem to sync them

-Google Music

This is what I was planning on using, until I found out that it only can save to internal memory (there's bad coverage where I live, so I can't rely on streaming)

-DoubleTwist

From what I've seen, DoubleTwist is an iTunes replacement, and doesn't sync from the iTunes application (so if I get new songs I would have to add them to iTunes then DoubleTwist)

Is there some amazing solution that I'm missing, or do I have to make do with one of these (and if so, which one would you recommend)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess since no one else answered, I'll post what I ended up doing as an answer.

The solution that worked best for me was **iSyncr**. It's a Mac/PC app that acts as a middleman between iTunes and your device, so you can sync all your iTunes music, playlists, and song data.

It wasn't perfect or free, but it was what worked the best for me.